# Getting clone method called on non-object when specing Symfony command that uses SymfonyStyle for styled output

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, tdd, phpspec

I'm trying to spec Symfony command and I want to have formated output with SymfonyStyle

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;

class SomeCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    //....
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);

        $io->title('Feed import initiated');
    }
}
```

and spec file:

```
<?php

namespace spec\Acme\AppBundle\Command;

use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class SomeCommandSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    //...
    function it_fetches_social_feeds(
        ContainerInterface $container,
        InputInterface $input,
        OutputInterface $output,
        SymfonyStyle $symfonyStyle
    ) {
        // With options
        $input->bind(Argument::any())->shouldBeCalled();
        $input->hasArgument('command')->shouldBeCalled();
        $input->isInteractive()->shouldBeCalled();
        $input->validate()->shouldBeCalled();

        $symfonyStyle->title(Argument::any())->shouldBeCalled();

        $this->setContainer($container);
        $this->run($input, $output);
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
exception [err:Error("__clone method called on non-object")] has been thrown.
 0 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Style/SymfonyStyle.php:50
   throw new PhpSpec\Exception\ErrorException("__clone method called on ...")
 1 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:866
   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run([obj:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput], [obj:Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput])
 2 vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:193
   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand([obj:PhpSpec\Console\Command\RunCommand], [obj:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput], [obj:Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput])
 3 vendor/phpspec/phpspec/src/PhpSpec/Console/Application.php:102
   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun([obj:Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput], [obj:Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput])
 4 vendor/phpspec/phpspec/bin/phpspec:26
   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
 5 vendor/phpspec/phpspec/bin/phpspec:28
   {closure}("3.2.2")
```

on line 50 of SymfonyStyle is:

```
public function __construct(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $this->input = $input;
    /* line 50 */ $this->bufferedOutput = new BufferedOutput($output->getVerbosity(), false, clone $output->getFormatter());
    // Windows cmd wraps lines as soon as the terminal width is reached, whether there are following chars or not.
    $this->lineLength = min($this->getTerminalWidth() - (int) (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR === '\\'), self::MAX_LINE_LENGTH);

    parent::__construct($output);
}
```

and phpspec is complainig about

```
clone $output->getFormatter()
```

Am I doing something wrong, or am I missing something?

**Update**

this is my `let` method:

```
function let(SymfonyStyle $symfonyStyle, InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $symfonyStyle->beConstructedWith([$input->getWrappedObject(), $output->getWrappedObject()]);
}
```

Comment: have you the `let` function? How do you specify how this SUS (system under spec) is created?

Comment: Added `let` function. @DonCallisto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing this

```
function it_fetches_social_feeds(
    ContainerInterface $container,
    InputInterface $input,
    OutputInterface $output,
    SymfonyStyle $symfonyStyle
) {
    // .... other code  
    $prophet = new Prophet();
    $formatter = $prophet->prophesize(OutputFormatterInterface::class);
    $output->getFormatter()->willReturn($formatter);
    // .... more code
}
```

You can place it where you want but before the call is done.

In that way you have created a `Stub` that is basically a `Double` with behavior and without expectations. You can see it as a "proxy" that will intercept method calls and returns what you "teach" it to return.
In your example things get broken as your double `OutputInterface` would return `null` as it's not a "real" object.
I also suggest to stub the `getVerbosity` behavior if you need to do different kind of specs.

BTW you can read more about doubles in [phpspec guide](http://www.phpspec.net/en/stable/manual/prophet-objects.html#prophet-objects) and [prophecy guide](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy#how-to-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at an [example](https://codegists.com/code/symfony-custom-command/), SymfonyStyle never seems to be passed in the spec class.
The execute function of the command doesn't pass it either, just the input and output classes (the style class it created as a local variable).

Comment: I really did not understand your answer. Could you please elaborate and provide some example?